# Action Bar show after loading screen

Tags: java, android

I made a loading screen/splash screen and deactivated the action bar in the styles.xml (with NoActionBar). But I want to have the Action Bar back after the loading screen is finished. I tried a method but after I applied this the app stops after the time that I set in the activity for the splash screen. So know I want to know what I can do that it function.

```
This is my code for the splash screen:
package com.example.jan.jhmtest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StartSreeen extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView tv;
private ImageView iv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_sreeen);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);

        Animation myanmin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytransition);

        tv.startAnimation(myanmin);
        iv.startAnimation(myanmin);

        final Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the Main acitvity

```
package com.example.jan.jhmtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason Your App is not rendering Toolbar is because your not setting toolbar as a action bar . sounds confusing right but bear with me and follow these steps .

**you set**

> parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" as a parent theme for your global app settings , this is the reason your splash has no action bar . Great this is what you wanted

Now for the rest of the screen you want toolbar as your action bar so lets just assume you add a toolbar to your layout like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/material_animations_primary"
    android:elevation="5dp">
```

Now your code I can see That initialised the toolbar properly like this

```
toolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

**but what you did wrong is not setting this toolbar as a support actionbar** 
N.B ToolBar is part of support library which is replacement Actionbar to make actionBar Backward compatible

**FIX**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

this will render your toolbar as actionbar 
for more details follow this blog post -> [Using the App Toolbar](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-app-toolbar)

Comment: I did this and then it says at setSupportActionBar(toolbar) it cannot be appield to v7.widdget.Toolbar